# psql's \set command unable to save json file's content in a variable

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am trying to below set command inside bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

psql -X -h localhost -U <dbuser> -d <dbname> <<EOF
CREATE TABLE cardtable(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, charcolumn VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, cardcolumn JSON NOT NULL);

\set var `cat /tmp/jsonfile.json`
INSERT INTO cardtable(charcolumn, cardcolumn) VALUES ('USA', :'var');

EOF
```

Content of jsonfile.json:

```
{
    "OT": [
        {
            "CD": 40,
            "ED": "2013-12-23",
            "ID": [
                "daf52501-330a-48a-d40988fa7a-a8",
            ]
         }
     ]
}
```

for some reason, the content of "`var`" was just `'{' !!` As a result `INSERT` command treats it as if the json data is of in-correct format and throws a syntax error.

Can someone please help me in understanding why "`\set`" command is behaving like this?

FYI: same command when executed manually at the `psql` prompt ends successfully!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There [here-doc feature in bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents) treats backticks as command invocations, so it executes the `cat /tmp/jsonfile.json`, which wrongfully injects the json contents into the psql commands:

> If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to
>   parameter expansion, **command substitution**, and arithmetic expansion,
>   the character sequence \newline is ignored, and ‘\’ must be used to
>   quote the characters ‘\’, ‘$’, and ‘`’.

You may quote the EOF word to remove all expansions, as in :

```
psql [...] << 'EOF'
... psql script...
\set var `cat /tmp/jsonfile.json`
...
EOF
```

That's the safest method when you don't need to inject anything from bash into the here-doc script.

Or, if any kind expansion in the here-doc string is needed, the above-mentioned characters must be quoted with backslash, as in:

```
myfile="/tmp/jsonfile.json"

psql [...] << EOF
... psql script...
\\set var \`cat $myfile\`
...
EOF
```